How can I rename the unique field constraint in the typeorm?
I made the field unique in the typeorm entity
when trying to save data, of course I get this error duplicate key value violates unique constraint IDX_a000cca60bcf04454e72769949
I want to enter the constrain name in this error myself, how can I enter it myself instead of auto generation
I tried @Unique('constrain_name', ['field']) but it didn't help
@Column({
    unique: true
})

I made unique in this method too, but I could not change the constrain name

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Personally I'd recommend using migration instead of synchronizing which solves such issue easily.
In case you need to use synchronization, it can be solved by providing namingStrategy. Though, this means you can't name it one-by-one.
import { DefaultNamingStrategy, type Table } from 'typeorm';

export class CustomNamingStrategy extends DefaultNamingStrategy {
  indexName(
    tableOrName: string | Table,
    columnNames: string[],
    where?: string | undefined,
  ): string {
    // sort incoming column names to avoid issue when ["id", "name"] and ["name", "id"] arrays
    const clonedColumnNames = [...columnNames];
    clonedColumnNames.sort();
    const tableName = this.getTableName(tableOrName);
    return `${tableName}_${clonedColumnNames.join('_')}_idx`;
  }

  uniqueConstraintName(
    tableOrName: Table | string,
    columnNames: string[],
  ): string {
    // sort incoming column names to avoid issue when ["id", "name"] and ["name", "id"] arrays
    const clonedColumnNames = [...columnNames];
    clonedColumnNames.sort();
    const tableName = this.getTableName(tableOrName);
    return `${tableName}_${clonedColumnNames.join('_')}_key`;
  }
}

then
const dataSource = new DataSource({
  namingStrategy: new CustomNamingStrategy(),
  ...others
})

You can refer to https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/blob/master/src/naming-strategy/DefaultNamingStrategy.ts#L120 for default naming strategy used.
